# To search a xml file using javascript or jquery [Edited]

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I loaded a xml file using jquery as shown below

```
       $(document).ready(function () {

          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "sample.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
           success: parseXml
         });

          function parseXml(xml) {


            $(xml).find("Details").each(function(){

            $("#output").append($(this).find("name").text());
            $("#output").append(": " + $(this).find("PhoneNumber").text() + "<br />");

             });
         }

    });
```

The sample.xml file format is as shown below

```
  <Details ID="34">
   <name>Joe</name>
    <PhoneNumber>
      <number1>12-11111</number1>
      <number2>13-67111</number2>
    </PhoneNumber>
  </Details>
  <Details ID="34">
   <name>Kumit</name>
    <PhoneNumber>
      <number1>12-156111</number1>
      <number2>6-7811</number2>
    </PhoneNumber>
  </Details>
```

Now I want to query the xml file like sql quires for database for two conditions that I mentioned below 
      1.get the PhoneNumber where name is Joe
     *(select PhoneNumber form table where name='Joe')*

      2.get the name where number1 or number2 matches 12-15611
     *(select name form table where number1 or number2='12-15611')*

Tell me how can I query the xml file for above two conditions using jquery or javascript

Comment: I think you meant 12-156111, right?

Comment: The XML doc needs a root node, unless you want to break it up it Details docs.

Comment: @Marc B  why it mentioned as duplicate I want to query the xml file like sql query for database for two conditions that I mentioned

Comment: Since this question goes further than just display the XML data it does not seem to be a duplicate of the one referenced. Perhaps the title is misleading. Would you want the PO to revise the title? @marcb